# Sprite builder sprites move to position (0,0) during run time. What could cause this?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I am relatively new to `Sprite-builder` (and `objective-c` for that matter). And I am confused by the behavior of a game program I am working on (mainly for educational proposes).

At the moment I have a scene named "`GameScene`" with a child named "Level1" where there are a number of ground sprites and a player sprite. When "`didLoadFromCCB`" completes the ground sprites have the correct position (as they were positioned in Sprite-builder). But I have noticed that by the time "update" runs for the first time their position changes to (0,0) (even the player node).

I am confused by this. They don't seem to move in the simulator, but I use their position to do some calculations later and this messes that up for me.

Has anyone else experienced this. Perhaps it is something simple I am doing wrong.

Here is the code that I thought would be of interest. But I can show more if you need it.

```
-(void) didLoadFromCCB

{
    //Enable Touch Events
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    //Load Level
    [self loadLevelNamed:nil];
    _GameButtonLayer.gameScene=self;
}

-(void) loadLevelNamed:(NSString*)levelCCB
{
    //Seeks out and finds physics node for Level
    CCNode* node = [self getChildByName:@"physics" recursively:YES];
    if ([node isKindOfClass:[CCPhysicsNode class]])
    {
        _physicsNode = (CCPhysicsNode*)node;
    }
    _drawPhysicsShapes = NO;
    _physicsNode.debugDraw = _drawPhysicsShapes;
    _physicsNode.collisionDelegate = self;
    //Seeks out and finds background node for Level
    _backgroundNode = [self getChildByName:@"background" recursively:YES];
    //Seeks out and finds player node for Level
    _playerNode = [self getChildByName:@"player" recursively:YES];
    NSAssert1(_playerNode, @"player node not found in level: %@", levelCCB);

    //Get grounds
    _ground1 = [self getChildByName:@"ground1" recursively:YES];
    _ground2 = [self getChildByName:@"ground2" recursively:YES];
    _ground3 = [self getChildByName:@"ground3" recursively:YES];
    _grounds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[_ground1, _ground2,     _ground3]];

    [self scrollToTarget:_playerNode];
}
```

Comment: just an intuition : try to move the call to `loadLevelNamed` from the `didLoadFromCCB`  method to the `onEnter` method (after calling [super onEnter] of this class). Order matters : i believe that `didLoadFromCCB` is invoked before `onEnter`, in which case any positions cant be resolved since the parent and parent's size are not known, which could cause confusion (possibly in your `scrollToTarget` method).

Comment: Perfect! It was partially this and partially having variables with similar names. Thanks so much!